# Single sign on between web application and native desktop application using OAuth 2

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4

We want to code a web-application (with ASP.NET Core) that starts a legacy Windows desktop application via a custom URL protocol. The web-application must use an authorization server for obtaining an access (bearer) token via OAuth 2 with which it has access to the user's resources via an ASP.NET Core Web API. The desktop application must be able to access the user's resources via the Web API too. How can the desktop application obtain an access token?

I can think of the following options:

1. The desktop application shows a login screen, sends the entered username and password to the authorization server (using the “Resource Owner Password Credentials” grant type of OAuth 2) and gets an access token back.
2. The desktop application shows an embedded browser window. The embedded browser requests the OAuth Authorize endpoint of the authorization server (using the “Authorization Code” grant type of OAuth 2) and the user must log-in to authorize. The authorization server redirects back to the redirect URL. The desktop application intercepts this redirect, extracts the authorization token and uses it to get an access token.
3. The web-application starts the desktop application and passes its access (bearer) token as an argument to the desktop application.
4. Before starting the desktop application, the web-application requests a new authorization code from the authorization server. The web-application starts the desktop application and passes the authorization code as an argument to the desktop application. The desktop application exchanges the authorization code for an access token by sending the authorization code to the OAuth Token endpoint of the authorization server.

We do not wish to use the first and second option, because we want single sign on.

The third option does not seem to be a good idea, because malicious software on the user’s desktop PC can obtain and use the access token too.

The fourth option seems to be the only option left. As far as I know an authorization code is a temporary (short-lived) one-time token. Besides that, you need to know the client secret for obtaining an access token.
Can anyone confirm that option four is the way to go? Or did I overlook something?

Are there any examples with IdentityServer for this scenario?

Comment: why can't both of your apps be client for auth server, then after logging into one user doesn't have to login into the other or am i missing something here. Also don't think passing the token is the best approach, kinda deceits the IdSrv purpose. Every client should authenticate itself and has its own access token

Comment: 4th Approach works. You can define custom redirect uri scheme which is the entry point to your desktop application. Once user logs in, the redirect uri scheme opens your Desktop app and passes the authrization code.

Comment: With OAuth the authorization code is passed to the client via a redirect URL. This redirect URL could be the URL with the custom protocol for starting the desktop application. The redirect URL could look something like this: MyCustomProtocol:CustomString?code=AUTHORIZAT‌​ION_CODE The desktop application receives the URI as a parameter and it can extract the authorization code from that. However, I think the authorization code is meant for the client that requested it and should not be passed to some other client. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Both application should share a logon session using the system browser. This way the user gets SSO in the native app (and even vice versa).

The spec describes the best practices for native apps:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-12

Comment: The web-application must pass the name of the browser in which it is running (e.g. “chrome.exe” or “firefox.exe”) to the native desktop application (via the custom URL). The desktop application must start this browser with the URL for the authorization request. The desktop application can specify a loopback redirect URI in the authorization request and must listen on the loopback interface for getting the auth code. By using the Proof Key for Code Exchange extension for OAuth the desktop application can prove that both the authorization and token request are made by the same application.

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is a flow that is made specially for desktop application:
[Client Device Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8628) for OpenID connect allows Application that do not have any "browser capability",this Flow will typically suit well Desktop applications.